# Is it possible to identify in jquery, if the user has clicked on "Call" or "Cancel"? when they receive a popup after clicking on <a href="tel:12345"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want them to redirect to other url if they select "Call" and it will stay on the same page if they select "Cancel"

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far?

Comment: $(window).load(function(){
   function autocall(){
  window.location="tel:123456";
   };

   window.setTimeout( autocall, 5000 ); // 5 seconds
})

Comment: This is an auto calling script when page loads

Comment: not likely and for good security reasons. Also you didn't mention what environment

Comment: Are you expecting user to click on an element within 5 seconds? How would you identify the click event where page recursively reloads?

Comment: When the page first loads, after 5 seconds they receives a pop up.

Comment: so, I am trying to recognize if they have clicked on call or cancel. This is a simple html page.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Good titles should not contain the majority of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is really rather vague and does not include an example. I would suggest that you prevent the default action and apply your own prompt.

This might look like:

**HTML**

```
<a href=“tel:415551212”>(415) 555-1212</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  $("a[href^='tel:']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Code for your Prompt
    var phoneNum = $(this).attr("href").substring(4);
    var results = prompt("Are you sure you want to call " + phoneNum + "?");
    if(results){
      window.location.href = "tel:" + phoneNum;
    }
    return false;
    }
  });
});
```

If you want to capture the results from another app, say if this is on a mobile device, there is no way to do that. The browser can only get details from it's own app due to security. So there is no way to find out if the user placed the call or not. But you can find out if they clicked the link to call, like I suggested above.